# spacemacs, problem with irony package when getting irony* from github as alternative location

Tags: spacemacs, github, irony-mode

I'm using spacemacs devel.

I've added following private layer using M-x configuration-layer/create-layer

```
(setq irony-packages
      '(
        company-irony
        company-irony-c-headers
        irony
        irony-eldoc
        ;; flycheck-irony ;; I'm not using it.
        ))

(defun irony/init-irony ()
  (use-package irony
    :defer t
    :commands (irony-mode irony-install-server)
    :init
    (progn
      (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
      (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-mode))
    :config
    (progn
      (setq irony-user-dir (f-slash (f-join user-home-directory "bin" "irony")))
      (setq irony-server-install-prefix irony-user-dir)
      (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq irony-additional-clang-options '("-std=c++11"))))
      (defun irony/irony-mode-hook ()
        (define-key irony-mode-map [remap completion-at-point] 'irony-completion-at-point-async)
        (define-key irony-mode-map [remap complete-symbol] 'irony-completion-at-point-async))

      (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony/irony-mode-hook)
      (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options))))

(when (configuration-layer/layer-usedp 'auto-completion)
  (defun irony/init-company-irony ()
    (use-package company-irony
      :if (configuration-layer/package-usedp 'company)
      :defer t
      :commands company-irony
      :init
      (progn
        ;;(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony)
        (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'company-irony-setup-begin-commands)))))

(when (configuration-layer/layer-usedp 'auto-completion)
  (defun irony/init-company-irony-c-headers ()
    (use-package company-irony-c-headers
      :if (configuration-layer/package-usedp 'company)
      :defer t
      :commands company-irony-c-headers
      :init
      (push 'company-irony-c-headers company-backends-c-mode-common))))

(when (configuration-layer/layer-usedp 'syntax-checking)
  (defun irony/init-flycheck-irony ()
    (use-package flycheck-irony
      :if (configuration-layer/package-usedp 'flycheck)
      :defer t
      :init (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'flycheck-irony-setup))))

(defun irony/init-irony-eldoc ()
  (use-package irony-eldoc
    :commands (irony-eldoc)
    :init
    (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-eldoc)))
```

then added irony to dotspacemacs-configuration-layers. After restart all is working well.

What I need to do is to use my github versions of all the packages listed above:

        `company-irony
        company-irony-c-headers
        irony
        irony-eldoc`

So what I did.

1. removed irony from dotspacemacs-configuration-layers.
2. restared emacs. This removed all the 4 irony packages from my system, which is OK.
3. edited dotspacemacs-additional-packages, then restared emacs:

`dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(w3m google-c-style flycheck-google-cpplint
                                          ;; I added the following.
                                          (irony :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/irony-mode"))
                                          (company-irony :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/company-irony"))
                                          (company-irony-c-headers :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/company-irony-c-headers"))
                                          (irony-eldoc :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/irony-eldoc"))
                                          )`

*Messages* log tells the following about the source of packages' installation:

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: company-irony@dotfile... [1/4]
Fetcher: github
Source: vibrys/company-irony

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: company-irony-c-headers@dotfile... [2/4]
Fetcher: github
Source: vibrys/company-irony-c-headers

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: irony@dotfile... [3/4]        ;; this on does NOT go from github.com. THis is my problem.

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: irony-eldoc@dotfile... [4/4]
Fetcher: github
Source: vibrys/irony-eldoc

The problem is that irony@dotfile does NOT go from github. It is taken from standard repository.

What am I doing wrong?

regards

Answer (score 0):

When I left only irony within the following

```
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(w3m google-c-style flycheck-google-cpplint
                                          (irony :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/irony-mode"))
                                          )
```

and layer packages.el file is also left with irony, ie:

```
(setq irony-packages
      '(
        irony))
```

then emacs restart installs it from github. *messages* tells:

```
(Spacemacs) --> installing package: irony@irony... [1/1]

Fetcher: github

Source: vibrys/irony-mode
```

So maybe the problem is that in case all four irony packages are going to be installed, then this irony package is already contained within one of the three thus installed earlier.

I changed the sequence of packages in packages.el then, so that:

```
(setq irony-packages
      '(
        irony
        irony-eldoc
        company-irony-c-headers
        company-irony
        ))
```

and changed sequence within `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`

```
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(w3m google-c-style flycheck-google-cpplint
                                          (irony :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/irony-mode"))
                                          (irony-eldoc :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/irony-eldoc"))
                                          (company-irony-c-headers :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/company-irony-c-headers"))
                                          (company-irony :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "vibrys/company-irony"))
                                          )
```

, then restarted emacs, and I've noticed that company mode is fetched just after `company-irony` has been fetched, even if it is installed in step [3/4]. This time the source is: Sarcasm/irony-mode, not: `vibrys/irony-mode`:

```
(Spacemacs) --> installing package: company-irony@irony... [1/4]

Fetcher: github

Source: vibrys/company-irony

....

Fetcher: github

Source: Sarcasm/irony-mode

....

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: company-irony-c-headers@irony... [2/4]

Fetcher: github

Source: vibrys/company-irony-c-headers

(Spacemacs) --> installing package: irony@irony... [3/4]


(Spacemacs) --> installing package: irony-eldoc@irony... [4/4]

Fetcher: github

Source: vibrys/irony-eldoc
```